# Cannot load maps using OpenLayers plugin in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, openlayers-2, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I'm currently using QGIS 2.12.1-Lyon. I have installed the OpenLayers Plugin (and updated to the latest version, v1.3.6). However, when I go to load up base maps in QGIS using this plugin (go to Web | OpenLayers plugin, then select a map) QGIS always throws a Python error.

The same error is always thrown. Some maps load, but most do not. Not at all sure why. I am still able to use the Google Hybrid base map for example, but not Google Streets.

Error dump is shown below (have changed user names and private folders for privacy).

```
An error has occured while executing Python code:

AttributeError: 'OpenlayersLayer' object has no attribute 'geometryType'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/matlab/.qgis2/python/plugins\BLNExporter\BLNExp.py", line 208, in EnablePlugin
    if (layer.geometryType() == QGis.Polygon) or (layer.geometryType() == QGis.Line) or (layer.geometryType() == QGis.Point):
AttributeError: 'OpenlayersLayer' object has no attribute 'geometryType'


Python version: 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] 
QGIS version: 2.12.1-Lyon Lyon, 16760fd 

Python Path:
C:/Users/joebloggs/.qgis2/python/plugins\processing
C:/PROGRA~1/QGISLY~1/apps/qgis/./python
C:/Users/joebloggs/.qgis2/python
C:/Users/joebloggs/.qgis2/python/plugins
C:/PROGRA~1/QGISLY~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib-1.3.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
C:\Users\joebloggs\.qgis2\python\plugins\opengeo\ext-libs\requests-2.0.1-py2.7.egg
C:\Users\joebloggs\.qgis2\python\plugins\opengeo\ext-libs\python_dateutil-2.2-py2.7.egg
C:\Users\joebloggs\.qgis2\python\plugins\opengeo\ext-libs\six-1.9.0-py2.7.egg
C:\Users\joebloggs\.qgis2\python\plugins\opengeo\ext-libs\lxml-3.3.5-py2.7-win32.egg
C:\Users\joebloggs\.qgis2\python\plugins\opengeo\ext-libs\gsimporter-0.2-py2.7.egg
C:\Users\joebloggs\.qgis2\python\plugins\opengeo\ext-libs\httplib2-0.9-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\tornado-4.0.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\backports.ssl_match_hostname-3.4.0.2-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\certifi-14.05.14-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\bin\python27.zip
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\DLLs
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\lib
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\lib\plat-win
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\lib\lib-tk
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\bin
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\jinja2-2.7.2-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\markupsafe-0.23-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytz-2012j-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\six-1.3.0-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlrd-0.9.2-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwt-0.7.5-py2.7.egg
C:/Users/joebloggs/.qgis2//python
C:\Users\joebloggs\.qgis2\python\plugins\opengeo\ext-libs
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\qgis\python\plugins\fTools\tools
C:/Users/joebloggs/Documents/RandomFolder/RandomSubFolder
```

Comment: I've given up on OpenLayers for base maps and am now a convert to the QuickMapServices plugin. Has google layers, OSM layers, and many others. Directly accesses map tiles and is less buggy than OL. I know this doesn't fix the problem you are having but might be useful.

Comment: Thanks, have done as suggested: QuickMapServices works very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue which was [recently logged here](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/13854) - the issue seems to be a recent 'map rollover' by google, which means the plugin author would need to make a code change. (In my case I don't get a crash, I just get a blank basemap)

I agree with @Spacedman suggestion to try [**QuickMapServices**](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/quick_map_services/). It appears that all the Google tile services currently work with that plugin (I think the issue is Leaflet-related, which might explain the difference between the two plugins)

Comment: OK thank you very much, also thanks to @Spacedman. I have done as you suggested and installed QuickMapServices. It has lots of maps and works very well. Hopefully they can fix the bug in the OpenMapLayers plugin :)